# Read lpstat output in reverse order?

Tags: printing, cat

Is it possible to make `lpstat` output print jobs in reverse order, from newer to older?
Starting from the end of file?

Currently we see in the output the first sent document, then the second, etc.

I have more than 5K jobs and I want to output only the ones new for me, cancelling the cycle once I reach the last job id I printed in screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can using `tac`:

```
lpstat | tac
```

If you want to revert order only, let say, last 10 lines, combine your command with `tail`:

```
lpstat | tail -n 10 | tac
```

Comment: Thanks but that would involve getting all the output, 5000 jobs, and pass it to tac to revert. I don't want to process all 5000 jobs that I already know, just the latest ones. Suppose I have 5000, and I get the list, then I send 2 more jobs, I only want to get those 2 jobs without walking all the jobs again.

Comment: @Jorge See my new edits.